# IOS how to select some rows in database (CoreData)

Tags: ios, database, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using coredata and save 20 rows in database.

In my database, I have saved 1 colum is "date". And now, I want to select data from date1 to date2.

How to I can do this.

Comment: How have you tried doing it? What went wrong?

Comment: I worked NSArray *arr = [TableName MR_findAll];

Comment: I got all data from TableName. But I only get some rows,

Comment: In my database have colum date:
I want to If you choose from date 18/10/2015 to date 19/10/2015.
I only get data inside this date.

Comment: Do you understand me?

Comment: So did you look at any of the predicate methods?

Comment: Of course! Can you help me about this problem?

Comment: Can you show how you tried with a predicate method, and the predicate you used, and explain what it did wrong (returned the wrong data, no data, raised an error, threw an exception)